# UITabelView cell reuseIdentifire

Tags: uitableview

My ques is very simple and clear about using reuseIdentifier for uitableview that if we have 100 count of array inside method numberOfRowsInSection then how many cell will be allocated in memory.

Anybody briefly explain this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS will only allocate enough cells to fill the screen, plus a few more as a buffer to show quickly when you scroll.  It queues cells for reuse when they go off the screen.   So generally you can expect that the number allocated at any given time is close to the number currently on the screen.

Comment: and what about the memory allocation ..? i knew cells are reuse later